# How to implement a Configuration Menu with Perl

Tags: perl, menu

I am trying to implement some kind of console menu wich has to retrieve a lot of parameters from user in order to build an XML in the end. At every step I need to do some checks on the given parameters but ofcourse those checks are different every step. Is there an easy library that can help me? With easy I mean something that already offers a pattern, I don't want to write thousands lines of codes.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

What about one of these modules:

- [Term::Menus](http://search.cpan.org/~reedfish/Term-Menus-2.12/lib/Term/Menus.pm)
- [Getopt::Std](http://search.cpan.org/~dapm/perl-5.10.1/lib/Getopt/Std.pm)